# Reference request for 2-categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, 2-categories

After a year of learning category theory, it seems to me that one needs to go at least as far as notions that are really 2-categorical, in order to see the real beauties of the subject. I know there is a chapter of CWM dedicated to 2-categories and that is certainly at my desk but here is another paper which it seems highly cited in the literature and beside, it's written by (also) gifted expositors:

> *Review of the elements of 2-categories* _ G. M. Kelly, Ross Street.

Unfortunately, I am some one out of academia and read out of curiosity and the bad news for me was there was no where I could find this paper for free. So, I was wondering if anyone can kindly help me with finding this paper.

Also, I would be very much appreciative if some one introduce me to a good reference for the subject.
 Many thanks

Comment: You could have a look at [_A 2-categories companion_](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702535), but it isn't quite as complete as one might like.

Comment: Nice, but not a single definition.

Answer (score 3):

To start seeing something about bi-categories I've really liked [Leinster's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810017).

Instead for studying some 2/bi-category theory more deeply I've found good enough  chapter 7 of Borceux's book "Handbook of categorical algebra 1".

Of course these aren't complete references but to start I believe that can be good enough.

By the way if those above aren't enough try to take a look to [2-category nlab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category), and more generally try to take a look at [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/) where you can find a lot more about ordinary and higher category theory.

Hope this helps.